# Why don't all Mint 12 applications show up in my cairo-dock menu?

Tags: linux-mint, menu, application

I'm running Mint12 with four monitors. Needless to say, the standard Gnome doesn't work well but it does when using `Cairo-Dock` instead of the default toolbars and menus.

The problem is that my application menu for `Cairo-Dock` is not the same as the default menu for Mint and some programs are not showing up.

The add-on Mint menu doesn't work, probably due to issues with `compiz`.

Compiz does not play nice when using two different cards with `xinerama`.

How can I load the get it to show the same applications?